# Optimization problem: x and y that minimizes x^H A y

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, bilinear-form

I have a problem formulated as:

$\underset{x,y}{\min} x^HAy$ subject to $\sum x = 1$ and $\sum y = 1$.

Where A is a complex matrix, and x and y are column vectors that I need to find.

This is very similar to the following convex optimization problem (e.g., minimum variance portofolio), $\underset{x}{\min} x^HAx$ subject to $\sum x = 1$, which has an analytical solution

$x = \frac{A^{-1} 1}{1^H A^{-1} 1} $, given that A is invertible. Does my problem have a similar solution? Or is there a technique to find the appropriate x and y via bilinear programming?

Comment: I would be tempted to alternatingly solve the regularized least squares problems $\min_x |x^H A y|_2^2 + \epsilon |1^Hx - 1|_2^2$ and $\min_y |x^H A y|_2^2 + \epsilon |1^Hy- 1|_2^2$, in other words iteratively switching between treating x and y as variables and constants. Presumably it can be pissoble to find a sequence of $\epsilon$ which give nice convergence.

Comment: I guess that you also have the constraints $x \ge 0$ and $y \ge 0$? This is a nonconvex optimization problem. I would not be surprised, if it has some combinatorial aspect, i.e., finding a solution might be very hard.

Comment: There are no constraints that x and y is larger than 0. The entries can be anything as long as the sum is 1. Also, thanks for the replies!